# Removing Project fails with error message.

Tags: git, gitlab

**Error message after failed delete project**

I am getting the following error while trying to delete a project from GitLab. This project was scheduled for deletion, but failed with the following message:

`Failed to remove project repository. Please try again or contact administrator`

The project has not been deleted and I have the above message on the project homepage. why is that happening? how could i delete a project which is no longer needed?

I also tried deleting inside the advanced settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try This one**

1.Settings --> Advanced --> Rename repository
Change the Path then press “Rename project” button.

2.Logout/Login

3.Settings --> Advanced --> Remove project
works.

New project is also work without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and had to remove all CI/CD - Pipelines - Pipeline entries by simply clicking on the pipeline id e.g. #123 and then on the 'Delete' button presented in the upper right corner of the opened panel.